# Compare multidimensional array with array of keys only

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
"fields" => {
    "name": "John"
    "lastname": "Doe"
  }
  "data" => {
    "person": array:2 [
      0 => {
        "adress": "foo"
        "phone": "bar"
      },
      1 => {
        "adress": "foo1"
        "phone": "bar1"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now I want to check that in this multidimensional array the follow keys exist so my second array to compare looks like this:

```
[
    'fields' => [
        "name",
        "lastname",
    ],
    "data" => [
        "person" => [
            "adress",
            "phone"
        ]
    ],
]
```

Now here's what I've tried to compare the keys of my second array with the first array:

```
$result = array_diff_key($firstArray, array_flip($secondArray));
```

But this gives me an

> array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!

So I need a way to recursively flip the array or maybe I am doing it a bit wrong

Comment: This is because if you use `array_fip()` on the 2nd array you have, it will attempt to set the key itself to an array, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a multidimensional array that looks like this ...

This is not an array, whatever you've done it now is amorphous trash, not an array not an json object.

> $result = array_diff_key($firstArray, array_flip($secondArray));

```
array_diff_key()    finds differences - unique keys
array_flip()        replaces keys with values in the array
```

> So I need a way to recursively flip the array or maybe I am doing it a bit wrong

Don't flip arrays, stop searching differences if you want to find the same keys.
You need at least 2 arrays (or objects) to comparison. If you will have 2 (not nested) arrays use

```
array_intersect_key($array1,$array2);
```

For nested arrays... you have to get all the keys and then compare.